# Modify Outliner with python

Tags: python, add-on, outliner, panel

I wrote a simple addon to toggle the Camera Ray visibility of multiple elements, something I'm constantly doing in my workflow.

[image: camera ray visibility]

I'd love to be able to modify the Outliner panel to add a new column controlling this attribute like the mock up below, but I was unable to find where the outliner tree is created in the code.

[image: outliner modification]

I need something more complex than the current panel I have (Quick Camera Ray), something that would let me know in a glance which meshes are camera visible or not, just like the outliner icons do with viewport/render visibility. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a [small python script](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_outliner.py) that handles the header and menus for the outliner, most of the outliner drawing is handled in [C source files](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_outliner/outliner_draw.c;97eefc1fd9069794cbfbba23de01fc1813f738d7$1787). This means that customising the outliner appearance requires a custom build of blender, though you can add menus as [shown here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6898/935).

I would suggest you keep using the panel in the properties editor that you have already started with.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I might add the operators to the outliner to at least make the toggle easily accessible. Thanks for the help!