# Clear restrict selection

Tags: outliner

I have several objects disabled for selection in the outliner (the little selection arrow is grayed out). How can I make everything in my scene available for selection without toggling each outliner item on one by one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/how-to-toggle-visibible-selectable-renderable-for-multiple-objects

Comment: you can select multiple objects in the outliner, right click and and toggle selectability  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UO80.gif

Answer (score 2):

In addition to cegaton's useful advice:

If you hold LMB on the top arrow and just drag down, it will turn on all the ones you cross on your way down.

It basically copies the first adjustment you made to all others. Photoshop had that in 2001. I suggested it in 2008, Ton probably forgot and someone else put it in unrelated to my suggestion ( :